# In Cypress Dashboard title is displaying as No Commit Message available, how can we set static message:

Tags: cypress

In Cypress Dashboard title is displaying as No Commit Message available, how can we set static message which we want to publish, I have not configured Cypress Dashboard with Github

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you need but you could use [tags](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#Commands)

```
cypress run --record --key foo tag="bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but you can do it using the environment variable `COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE` (if you do anything like `cypress run ....` it will pick it up from there if it can't find via your git history.

You can find more about this in the documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Git-information